# Import result from api to datebase

Tags: php, wordpress, api

I import phone specifications by using the `FonoApi` via `PHP`. Through `str_replace`, I receive data on the page in `Polish`. Often new models are not available in the database so quickly and so they are added manually in custom fields.

I would like the data imported from the API after changing the language to be saved in the custom fields of the given model.

**This is my initial code:**

```
include_once("fonoapi-v1.php");

$apiKey = "key"; // get your token key here - https://fonoapi.freshpixl.com
$fonoapi = fonoApi::init($apiKey);

$month = array('January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December','Not announced yet');
$replace = array('Styczeń','Luty','Marzec','Kwiecień','Maj','Czerwiec','Lipiec','Sierpień','Wrzesień','Październik','Listopad','Grudzień','Brak danych');

$typ = array ('colors','capacitive touchscreen');
$typ_zamiana = array('kolorów',', ekran pojemnościowy');

$lcd = array ('inches','screen-to-body ratio','pixel');
$lcd_zamiana = array('cala','powierzchni telefonu','');

$wielkosc = array ('pixels','density');
$wielkosc_zamiana = array('px','gestość pikseli');

$kolor = array ('Blue','Pink','Gold','Black','Smoky niebieski','White','Titanium','Midnight czarny','Maple złoty','Deep Sea niebieski','Star','(Taiwan only)','Grey','Orchid szary','Jet czarny','Rose złoty','Silver','Red','Haze złoty','tytanowy szary');
$kolor_zamiana = array('niebieski','różowy','złoty','czarny','smoky blue','biały','tytanowy','midnight black','maple gold','deep sea blue','','','szary','orchid grey','jet black','rose gold','srebrny','czerwony','haze gold','titanium grey');

$usb = array ('reversible connector');
$usb_zamiana = array('złącze dwustronne');

$ochrona = array ('Scratch-resistant glass','Ion-strengthened glass, oleophobic coating');
$ochrona_zamiana = array('szkło odporne na zarysowania','wzmocnione włóknem szkło, powłoka olejofobowa');

 try {

     $res = $fonoapi::getDevice(); // the device you need to get details here

     $i = 0;
     foreach($res as $mobile) if ($i < 1) {

         if (!empty($mobile - > announced)) echo "<p><strong>Wprowadzono na rynek: </strong> ".$mobile - > announced = str_replace($month, $replace, $mobile - > announced).
         "</p>";
         if (!empty($mobile - > type)) echo "<p><strong>Typ wyświetlacza: </strong>".$mobile - > type = str_replace($typ, $typ_zamiana, $mobile - > type).
         "</p>";
         if (!empty($mobile - > size)) echo "<p><strong>Wielkość wyświetlacza: </strong>".$mobile - > size = str_replace($lcd, $lcd_zamiana, $mobile - > size).
         "</p>";
         if (!empty($mobile - > resolution)) echo "<p><strong>Rozdzielczość wyświetlacza: </strong>".$mobile - > resolution = str_replace($wielkosc, $wielkosc_zamiana, $mobile - > resolution).
         "</p>";
         if (!empty($mobile - > colors)) echo "<p><strong>Dostępne kolory: </strong>".$mobile - > colors = str_replace($kolor, $kolor_zamiana, $mobile - > colors).
         "</p>";
         if (!empty($mobile - > protection)) echo "<p><strong>Ochrona wyświetlacza: </strong>".$mobile - > protection = str_replace($ochrona, $ochrona_zamiana, $mobile - > protection).
         "</p>";
         if (!empty($mobile - > usb)) echo "<p><strong>Typ złącza: </strong>".$mobile - > usb = str_replace($usb, $usb_zamiana, $mobile - > usb).
         "</p>";
         $i += 1;
     }

 } catch (Exception $e) {
     if (get_field('pokaz-tak')) {

         echo '<p><strong>Wprowadzono na rynek:</strong> '.get_field('rynek').
         '</p>';
         echo '<p><strong>Typ wyświetlacza:</strong> '.get_field('typlcd').
         '</p>';
         echo '<p><strong>Wielkość wyświetlacza:</strong> '.get_field('wielkosc_wyswietlacza').
         '</p>';
         echo '<p><strong>Rozdzielczość wyświetlacza:</strong> '.get_field('rozdzielczosc').
         '</p>';
         echo '<p><strong>Dostępne kolory:</strong> '.get_field('kolory').
         '</p>';
         echo '<p><strong>Ochrona wyświetlacza:</strong> '.get_field('ochrona_wyswietlacza').
         '</p>';
         echo '<p><strong>Typ złącza:</strong> '.get_field('typ_zlacza').
         '</p>';

     } else {

         echo 'Nie posiadamy w bazie danych technicznych do tego modelu.';

     }
 }
```

`getDevice` is downloaded from `get_the_title`.

Comment: Could you reduce this to [a minimum, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: My initial code sits in the single.php file from wordpress. FonoApi is available on github.